# Php Jquery Autocomplete,

Tags: php, jquery

I have a autocomplete input and an [ADD button] in main page.
Pressing add button, user is redirect to add new record.
After saving new record, user is redirect back to main page.

**I'm like, when user is redirected to main page, have input field filled up with this addedd record data**

How to accomplish this?

Here my code:

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Sender <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" id="sender_name" name="sender_name" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to select" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="sender_id" name="sender_id">
</div>
```

AJAX

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#sender_name" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'add_document_sender_autocomplete.php',
            minLength: 1, 

            change: function (event, ui) {
                if (!ui.item) {
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            },

            select: function(event, ui) {

                $('#sender_id').val(ui.item.id);

            }


        });
    });
```

QUERY

```
//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
//get matched data from skills table

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT sender_id, sender_vat_tax_code, sender_name, sender_foreign_name FROM rm_senders WHERE replace(replace(replace(sender_vat_tax_code, '.', ''), '-', ''), '/', '')  LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' OR concat_ws(' ', sender_name, sender_foreign_name) LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY sender_name ASC");

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

$data[] = array (
 'id' => $row['sender_id'],
 'label' => '('.$row['sender_vat_tax_code'].') '. $row['sender_name'].' '.$row['sender_foreign_name'],
);

}

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I'm curious; is this a live website? I hope not.

Comment: under development yet, why you hope not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must import this js libraries

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.24/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Sender <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="sender_name" name="sender_name" required="required" class="form-control"
           placeholder="Type to select" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="sender_id" name="sender_id">
</div>
```

AJAX

```
$(function () {
    $("#sender_name").autocomplete({
        source: 'add_document_sender_autocomplete.php',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var sel = ui.item;
            $('#sender_id').val(sel.id);
        },
        minLength: 1,
        autoFocus: false,
        delay: 250,
        response: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length == 1 && ui.content[0].id != 0) {
                ui.item = ui.content[0];
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                $(this).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
            }
        },
    });
});
```

QUERY

```
$return_arr = array();

$tget = "%" . $_GET['term'] . "%";
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT sender_id, sender_vat_tax_code, sender_name, sender_foreign_name FROM rm_senders WHERE replace(replace(replace(sender_vat_tax_code, '.', ''), '-', ''), '/', '')  LIKE '%" . $searchTerm . "%' OR concat_ws(' ', sender_name, sender_foreign_name) LIKE '%" . $searchTerm . "%' ORDER BY sender_name ASC");
//print_r($stock);
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row->sender_id;
    $row_array['label'] = '(' . $row['sender_vat_tax_code'] . ') ' . $row['sender_name'] . ' ' . $row['sender_foreign_name'];
    array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
}
die(json_encode($return_arr));
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your time, I understant need to pass ID as variable to get data, right? In this case i create a variable SEL var sel = ui.item;  $('#sender_id').val(sel.id);